# Difference between query string and path parameter in play framework?

Tags: scala, playframework

I'm learning play framework by my self.
What is the difference between a query string and a path parameter in routers? and what is the difference between `PathBindable` and `QueryStringBindable` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's described in the documentation:

https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/ScalaRouting
https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/ScalaRequestBinders

In a short, path parameter is a parameter in the URL:

```
# Client, like /clients/125
GET   /clients/:id          controllers.Clients.show(id: Long)
```

Query string parameters are query string parameters:

```
# Pagination links, like /clients?page=3
GET   /clients              controllers.Clients.list(page: Int ?= 1)
```

You can see that in this example Play binds parameters from string to other types, like `Long` and `Int`. There are situations when you want to bind parameters to other types, then you need to write your own binder. `PathBindable` for path parameter and `QueryStringBindable` for query parameters.

So, if you can bind client id to client you can write

```
# Client, like /clients/125
GET   /clients/:id          controllers.Clients.show(client: Client)
```

And the binder:

```
implicit def pathBinder(implicit intBinder: PathBindable[Int]) = new PathBindable[Client] {
  override def bind(key: String, value: String): Either[String, Client] = {
    for {
      id <- intBinder.bind(key, value).right
      client <- Client.findById(id).toRight("Client not found").right
    } yield client
  }
  override def unbind(key: String, client: Client): String = {
    client.id.toString
  }
}
```

If you want to have full control over URL parsing and binding, you can go even further and use [String Interpolating Routing DSL](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/ScalaSirdRouter)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but when i'm trying to add `GET         /quizz/:sourceLang                                             controllers.Quiz.quiz(sourceLang: play.api.i18n.Lang, targetLang: play.api.i18n.Lang)` to the routes file play complain that `No QueryString binder found for type play.api.i18n.Lang. Try to implement an implicit QueryStringBindable for this type.`. I understand what is a query string but i couldn't understand what should i get this error message.

Comment: Sorry, i didn't read the book carefully. Error is about `targetLang` parameter. _Any parameter that’s passed to the action generation method and isn’t specified as a path parameter is inferred to be part of the request’s query string_